# Library not found for -lRNAppleAuthentication

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I am integrating apple authentication using react-native-apple-authentication. But getting a linking error.
Steps I followd:

- yarn add @invertase/react-native-apple-authentication
- cd ios && pod install

[image]